# Writing multiple lists to a file

Tags: python

I have 2 lists and an output file sent to a function  I am having an issue with how to do the .write statement.

I have tried using an index, but get list error.

```
nameList = ['james','billy','kathy']
incomeList = [40000,50000,60000]
```

I need to search the lists and write the name and income to a file.

```
  for income in incomeList:
      if income > 40000:
          output.write(str("%10d    %12.2f \n")  # (this is what I can't figure out)))
```

Comment: Where are the names in your example code, don't they matter? What is you cannot figure out? What format do the lines need to be in?

Comment: What you want to write

Comment: In plain English, what do you think are the steps required to create the desired output line?

Comment: @Shadowcodder  
I am trying to get the second half of the .write statement...everything I have tried has errored.

Comment: please post an output of of how the file should look

Comment: @Grismar  
<br/>
I have tried several things on the .write part of the statement and I can't get the data elements to appear, I keep getting list errors.
<br/>
Last thing I tried was  
```  
ind = incomeList.index(income)
output.write(str("%10d    %12.2f   \n"  %   (namelist(ind),inclome)))  
```
  
that gave me a list error when I ran it

Comment: @kenan  billy    50000  <br/>kathy   60000

Sorry but edit commands are not working...I have been putting 2 spaces at the end of each line and it still won't do the line break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
nameList = ['james','billy','kathy']
incomeList = [40000,50000,60000]
for k, v in zip(nameList, incomeList):
    if v > 40000:
        print(k,v )
```

Output :-

```
 billy 50000
 kathy 60000
```

Comment: Thank you  that worked and explained zip function...yes I am just learning to program python.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
for i,income in enumerate(incomeList):
      if income > 40000:
          output.write(str(nameList[i]) )
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of 2 lists, I would suggest using a dict.

```
nameIncomeList = {'james':40000,'billy':50000,'kathy':60000}
```

For multiple case scenario,

```
f=open('f1.txt','w')
for i in range(len(nameList)):
    if incomeList[i]>40000:
        f.write(nameList[i]+' '+incomeList[i]+'\n')

f.close()
```

Comment: thank you , but I was given the lists and can't recombine them

Comment: Then the second solution will help you.